# How to disable a form submit button "a là Ruby on Rails Way"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to *disable* and *toogle the CSS class* of a `form.submit` *when the form is AJAX submitted and until the AJAX HTTP request is completed* (I am using the default jQuery framework for JavaScript).

My form is the following:

```
<%= form_for(@article, :remote => true) do |form| %>
    ...
    <%= form.submit(nil, {:id => 'button_id', :class => 'button_class'}) %>
<% end %>
```

**How can I make that in a "common"/"good"/"proper" way?**

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Rails jQuery bridge (jquery_ujs.js) code actually has a helper for this.

```
<%= form.submit "Save", id: "button_id", class: "button", disable_with: "Submitting..."
```

It will replace the button text with the value you give.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag

**API change:** as Renan suggests in a comment below, as of [Rails 4 beta](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0.beta1/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L426) there is a deprecation notice on the `disable_with` option. It should be changed to be a data attribute:

```
<%= form.submit "Save", id: "button_id", class: "button", data: {disable_with: "Submitting..."} %>
```

This should work with all recent versions of Rails as it's what the option did anyway. So it'll be one less deprecation notice to fix when you upgrade to Rails 4. :)

Comment: So, isn't there a jQuery bridge for the `form.submit` but only for the `submit_tag`?

Comment: The `submit` method of the `FormBuilder` calls `submit_tag` with the options passed on.

Comment: `disable_with` option was deprecated as of rails 3.2.5. Now use `:data => {:disable_with => 'Submitting...'}`. Source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag#1305--disable-with-is-deprecated

Comment: There's no deprecation notice in the latest 3.2.13 release of Rails but it is in the 4.0.0-beta1 so I've updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks.