# prevent double click with disable_form, ruby on rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, double-click

I'm trying to prevent a form from being "double posted", when the user either clicks twice or hits submit twice.

I've seen a couple posts on this, but they haven't hit this issue per se.  I can't seem to get the below to stop double-posts, and I'm getting the feeling it's related to the remote => true (using ajax to show the content on the page).

Below is my form:

```
    <%= form_for([@posts, @comment], :remote => true) do |f| %>

      <%= f.text_field :comment %>

      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary", :style => 'display: none;', :disable_with => '' %>

    <% end %>
```

Any recommendations would be great.  Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505801/prevent-double-submits-in-a-rails-ajax-form

Comment: it works fine for "clicking" but doesn't work for when someone hits enter...which is what people do when you hide the submit button.  That's why this question is different from the one on the link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the disable_with option

```
<%= submit_tag :submit, :id => 'submit_button', :value => "Create!", disable_with: "Creating..." %>
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is currently broken on Safari (8.0.3, in my case). See: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/306 If anyone has a sane workaround, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Please update the answer for newer Rails versions, see the answer below.

Answer (score 10):

The other answer didn't work for me — I believe it was from the Rails 2 era. According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag), the `disable_with` attribute should be added within a `data` attribute, like so:

```ruby
<%= submit_tag "Complete sale", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." } %>
```

Comment: Yeah, old answers, this one worked perfectly, thanks.