# A way to prevent user from posting twice by accident?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What are some of the ways to prevent a users from clicking a button twice and inadvertently posting twice? Are there any methods specific to rails?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160204/in-rails-controllers-how-to-prevent-double-submit-when-user-double-clic-submit this might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [button_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag) helper includes an option, `:disable_with`. Using this option will disable the button (using unobtrusive JavaScript) when the form is submitted, preventing additional clicks.